# Outcomes from multiple Mystery Box

Tags: probability, combinations

A [mystery box](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/2039390) contains a single prize, which can be common (0.45 chance), uncommon (0.35) or rare (0.20). If I open once such box, the chance of getting a prize from each category is obvious.

If I open two boxes, there are 9 possible outcomes (3 rarities ^ 2 boxes). The boxes I open contain a rare item (R) and a common item (C), giving 0.2 * 0.45 = 0.09. However, as this outcome could also have been CR rather than RC, I multiple this by 2 to give 0.18, or 18%. Therefore, when opening two boxes, the chances of getting a rare and a common is 18%.

I'm trying to generalize this to an arbitrary number of boxes. Calculating the probability of one run of such boxes is straightforward based on the chances above, but determining how many times an outcome occurs is tricky.

For example, with four boxes, the outcome "UUUC" would occur 4 times, so I would multiply (0.35^3 * 0.45) by 4? "UUCC" would occur 6 times.

How can I generalize this so that I can enter the outcomes of an arbitrary number of boxes and determine the probability of having got that outcome? For example, I open 100 boxes and get UUCUCURCRUCC.... What is the probability of getting that configuration from 100 boxes, as in the "18%" example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the outcome $UUUC$ would occur only one time. Why? Because $C$ can take only the last position, and the rest will be taken by $U$s.

However, if the order isn’t important, then there are four sequences involving three $U$s and one $C$. Why? Because then $C$ can take any one of the four positions at hand, and the rest will be taken over by the $U$s.

In general, note that if *order isn’t important*, then in a sequence of $n$ outcomes, if there are $u$ number of $U$‘s, $c$ number of $C$’s and $r$ number of $R$’s, then the total number of possibilities are: $$\frac{n!}{u!\times c! \times r!}$$ The associated probability will then be : $$P = \frac{n!}{u!\times c!\times r!}(0.35)^u(0.45)^c(0.20)^r$$

This is also called a [multinomial distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

But, if the *order is important*, then the required probability is just: $(0.35)^u(0.45)^c(0.20)^r$.

Comment: Order isn't important, as it does not matter the order in which the boxes are opened.

Comment: @SabreWolfy Then you take only the concerned case!